# Ghost vulnerbilty - upgrade only affected packages

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, apt

regarding GHOST [vulnerbilty](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-your-linux-server-against-the-ghost-vulnerability):

How could I only upgrade affected packages which can be found like this (on ubuntu 12-04):

```
lsof | grep libc | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
```

I´m looking for a way to pipe output of lsof to apt like this:

```
apt-get update --install-only …
```

Thanks!

Comment: apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

Comment: Any running processes that use glibc do not use the new/fixed glibc until they are restarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to make per package updates. It's a system level update. 
Check this out: 
[How To Protect your Linux Server Against the GHOST Vulnerability](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-your-linux-server-against-the-ghost-vulnerability)

Comment: Ok thanks, but at this machine this would be a bit risky for me. I´ve now only updated/run apt with -security packages. and the vunerability is fixed.

Comment: @toni you need to restart the services that your `lsof` outputs (or reboot the server to be sure). If you just updated glibc, then your services are still vulnerable.